# Google Cloud Datastore: Update creates new Entity instead of updating existing one

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I got a problem using Google Cloud Datastore. So far I managed to get everything working except the UPDATE method... Whenever I want to update an existing entity, it creates a new one instead of updating the old one. I am positive that I give the correct id but right now I am really out of ideas. I searched for similar issues and found some:

- [Update query in google app engine data store (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679759/update-query-in-google-app-engine-data-store-java)
- [GAE Datastore - workaround for updating entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736287/gae-datastore-workaround-for-updating-entity)
- [Google Datastore - Problems updating entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528667/google-datastore-problems-updating-entity)

but was unable to fix my issues. I am using generated endpoints for now.

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String street_nr;
    private String city;
    private String zip;
    private String country;

    public Address(){ }

    public Long getKey(){
        return id;
    }

    public  String getStreet() {
        return street == null ? "" : street;
    }

    public void setStreet( String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public  String getStreetNr() {
        return street_nr == null ? "" : street_nr;
    }

    public void setStreetNr( String streetNr) {
        this.street_nr = streetNr;
    }

    public  String getCity() {
        return city == null ? "" : city;
    }

    public void setCity( String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public  String getZip() {
        return zip == null ? "" : zip;
    }

    public void setZip( String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public  String getCountry() {
        return country == null ? "" : country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

**Endpoint:**

```
@ApiMethod(
    name = "update",
    path = "address/{id}",
    httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.PUT)

    public Address update(@Named("id") Long id, Address address) throws NotFoundException {
        checkExists(id);
        ofy().save().entity(address).now();
        logger.info("Updated Address: " + address);
        return ofy().load().entity(address).now();
    }

private void checkExists(Long id) throws NotFoundException {
        try {
            ofy().load().type(Address.class).id(id).safe();
        } catch (com.googlecode.objectify.NotFoundException e) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Could not find Address with ID: " + id);
        }
    }
```

Where my server logs tells me that the address has been updated. Therefore I assume that checkExists(id) does its work as intended.

> com.PACKAGE.AddressEndpoint update: Updated Address: com.PACKAGE.models.Address@495871

**Helper:**

```
public static AddressApi getEndpoints() {

        // Create API handler
        final AddressApi.Builder builder = new AddressApi.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl(Constants.ROOT_URL)
                .setApplicationName(Constants.APPLICATION_NAME);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

**And finally the call:**

```
Address address = AddressBuilderHelper.getEndpoints().get(MY_KEY).execute();
address.setCity("San Francisco");
AddressBuilderHelper.getEndpoints().update(address.getKey(), address).execute();
```

Which then creates a new Entity just like insert does. I am out of ideas here :(

Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

***UPDATE***

Turns out the only thing that was missing is the setter for the id attribute. Adding it did the job!

Comment: I assume that the id on the Address object does not get set when it is marshalled/unmarshalled because there is no setter for it. Also, I don't understand why you are passing and checking the id separately from the address object.

Comment: Wow. You were spot on! Adding a setter did the job - thanks so much.